# Read Own Multiple Images from folder and Save as a Dataset for Training

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I am working on training my own images read from my folders. I would be thankful if you could help me for this.

I successfully read my all images from the folder and create my own onehot_encoded labels. However, in each time I run my code, it takes a lot of time to do read all images from the folders. Therefore, I want to create dataset from these images and save it like MNIST to use faster. Thus, I will not read my whole images again. Could you please help me for this?

The code is:

```
  path = "D:/cleandata/train_data/"
  loadedImages = []
  labels = []
  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  for i in range(len(os.listdir(path))):
        imagesList = listdir(path+os.listdir(path)[i])
        for image in imagesList:        
            image_raw_data_jpg tf.gfile.FastGFile(path+os.listdir(path)
            [i]+'/'+image, 'rb').read()  
            raw_image =tf.image.decode_png(image_raw_data_jpg,3)
            gray_resize=tf.image.resize_images(raw_image, [28, 28]) 
            image_data = 
            sess.run(tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(gray_resize))         
            loadedImages.append(image_data)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saving your dataset like MNIST?

Comment: I mean that I want to save all images' pixels and labels into two different dataset files and call them on python to use for training and testing purposes.

Comment: Reading shouldn't take too much time. Jpeg encode is just reading the values as it is. Are you rescaling/resizing the images

Comment: Yes, I do rescaling. I have about 6000 images. It takes a long time.

Comment: MNIST format is 1 byte label, (height * width * channels) bytes images.

Comment: Many Thanks for your all answers.
@Pam, I think it will be time consuming to write a code for me to create exactly same format of MNIST dataset. Is there any other alternative format that I can store those images as a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on how to use a TFRecords file. It shows how to create the file (containing images and labels) and read from it.

http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html

Or you could just use zipfile, and include the label in the image file name, thus keeping them together (that is what I did)